# how to Create 2 instances of SpeechRecognizer that can run in parallel/concurrently?

Tags: swift, speech-recognition

I want to create 2 Instance of SpeechRecognizer that can run in parallel , here is the code

```
func Selection_TButton(url : URL) {

    guard let newrecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
        print("No Speech Recognizer avaiable ")
        return
    }

    if !newrecognizer.isAvailable {
        print("recognizer is not availble")
        return
    }

    let recognitionRequest = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(
        url: url)
    newrecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest) { result, error in

        if (error != nil) {
            print("fails with error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if let result = result {

           self.TextView.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            print(result.isFinal)  

            if result.isFinal == true {
                let formattedString : String?
                formattedString = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            }
        }
```

And this is how i want to call this function by passing URL path

```
self.Selection_TButton(url: finalPath1)
self.Selection_TButton(url: finalPath2)
```

How can I accomplish this ?

I tried but it fires one SpeechRecognizer instances and fails other instance with error code

> error domain=kafassistanterrordomain code=209

Any advise on this ?

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your code? It's absurdly spaced out, it doesn't fit the code box without a scroll bar

Comment: Probably impossible.

Comment: @matt , can you suggest any other workaround ?

Comment: I don’t know what there is that needs to be worked around.

Comment: is there a way , i can run two speechrecognizertasks in parallel , any suggestions ?

Comment: I have also tried like this but it keeps giving me the same error that you mentioned above. Now, I think maybe there is restriction put on speech recognizer by Apple. Still, they have not mentioned anything in the docs regarding this. -https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizer
Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: Any news on this @RajatMishra ?

Comment: @MJQZ1347 Sorry but I didn’t do furthermore work in it as there were no leads to follow.